# Error when trying to make a process map in bupaR: factor level [12] is duplicated

Tags: r

Basically, what the title says. I have a very simple dataset with case id, timestamp and activity id, which I have transformed into an eventlog using the simple_eventlog functionin bupaR.

However, when I try to do anything with the dataset, including creating a process map, I get an error saying:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: factor level [12] is duplicated.

I've tried to look it up but honestly I've no idea what that error is referring to or how to fix it.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data using `dput()`?

Comment: Sure.

structure(list(Week = c(1, 1, 1 [etc]), Start = structure(c(1543449614.4, 
1543449703.8, 1543449790.9, [etc]), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Microprocesses = c("Planning", "Judging information", "Judging information", [etc])), row.names = c(NA, -151L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Where "week" is the case id, "start" is the timestamp and "microprocesses" are the action ids.